# Exception with BufferedOutputStream and HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, illegalstateexception

I am developing an Android application in which I downloading files from some servers.

**Code:**

```
myURL = new URL("abc.com");

myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();

myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
 myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream op = new BufferedOutputStream(myURLConnection.getOutputStream());
op.write(tokens.toByteArray());
op.close();
```

The code line `op.write(tokens.toByteArray());` is generating an exception "**illegalStateException: Did not write as much data as expected java**".

**QUESTION:**

1. What is the cause for this type of exception?
2. What is the coding solution for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the value of `tokens`?

Comment: Possible, length of your message does not match to length that expect server. Try to add request params like described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I will look for what information I am missing when posting a request to server.